# Android: AsyncTask onPostExecute setText crashed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I am really new to Android. Please give me some help. Thanks in advance!
The following code is part of the **second** activity

```
public class getInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public TextView textViewCityName;
    public TextView textViewTemp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewCityName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCityName);
        textViewTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp);
    ...
```

Then the **AsyncTask onPostExecute** code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Double aDouble) {
    //textViewCityName.setText("2172729");   //crashed the APP
    Toast.makeText(getInfoActivity.this, "2172729",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    //working
}
```

The Error Info

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

1. Why did the APP keep crashing when I changed the **TextView**?
2. Why did the **Toast** work?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure `R.layout.activity_main` is the right layout for your second `Activity`?

Comment: can you double check if `R.id.textViewCityName`? You didn't post much information about the logcat, but I'm assuming that `textViewCityName` is null

Comment: Thanks @Onik. It does solve all the problems. Sorry I am really new to Android.

Comment: can you share your activity_main xml

Answer (score 0):

Okay, use this `textViewCityName.get().setText("2172729");`